# Override Predefined Function inside a Class.

Tags: php, namespaces, overriding

I would like to override predefined functions inside a class using namespace

```
// one.class.php

class One{
  public function __construct($str){
    echo strtolower($str);
  }
}
```

Ok calling this would result

```
new One("mIxEd"); // mixed
```

I would like to override **strtolower** function inside **class One**

I tried to do this

```
// blabla.class.php
namespace blabla;
function strtolower($str){
  return strtoupper($str);
}
class One extends \One{};
```

Ok then when I put it all together

```
// script.php
require_once("one.class.php");
require_once("blabla.class.php");
new One("mIxEd"); // mixed
new blabla\One("mIxEd"); // mixed
```

The output it's still lowercase, so i'm not overriding strtolower inside class One.

I'm wandering if is even possibile...
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the constructor in blabla\One to call the namespaced strtolower.

```
class One extends \One {
   public function __construct($str) {echo strtolower($str);}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but is not what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to override predefined function

Comment: Ah sorry. I don't think there's a way to override it to force the base class to call your override. As you saw, you need to explicitly call it in the namespaced class.  Possibly a better way would be to abstract the strtolower in a member function and override that to do something else in the namespaced class?